# Equivalent of -webkit-text-stroke for FF and IE

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, webkit

I saw [somewhere](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke) that the style -webkit-text-stroke is not supported by **any** version of FF (or IE, for that matter but the last one is hardly a surprise). What can i do about it if i need to allow my Mozilla/Microsoft powered visitors to see the outlining.

I have the following solutions, none of which feels very right.

1. Forget about it and let people choose a better browser.
2. Join the Mozilla team and get employment at Microsoft to speed up the develpment
3. Use images for outlining and let Paint.NET do the job.
4. Wait until somebody else does something appropriate about that.

Suggestions?

Comment: Firefox 48 now supports "-webkit-text-stroke" as is. See the [Mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke)!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this blog](http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/), you can use shadows to simulate the effect.

Comment: So it won't work in one browser, instead of not working in all but one browser.  I'd still call that a win.  Besides, I'm sure IE has some kind of non-standard MS filter for achieving a similar effect.

Comment: I really can't be bothered for such a small feature. If it would be something big, i'll adapt it to the different browsers but just outlining the text is just not worth the hustle.

Comment: Yes it's not a big issue. but what if we have white text with black outline on a white page? this will make text unreadable on IE and other unsupported browsers

Comment: I know this is old but for any one visiting today, IE11 to support text-shadow https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-textshadow